# Redirect Link Code Without Quotation Marks

Tags: testing

Redirect Link Code Without Quotation Marks

Comment: *"The link Im trying to redirect it to has " marks in it"*... I don't see any quotation marks in that URL, what am I missing? Are you *sure* you want a meta refresh?

Comment: Yes, that link doesn't, but the one Im trying to add does. Thats just an example.

Comment: Is it a valid URL or not? I mean, why are there quotes in it?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Using PHP you can use `str_replace`:

```
$url = 'http://www.domain.com/"/';
$url = str_replace('"', '', $url);
```

Comment: How would I put that in a full PHP script? Sorry Im new at coding and not very advanced.

Comment: @user1869381 I don't know what your full PHP script looks like. But it appears you intend to put this in your header. So you would then use `echo '<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="1; url=' . $url . '">';`

Comment: Any comment for the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

You need to encode your link. For example, if this is your link:

```
http://example.com/test.php?val="quotations"&var=test
```

`"quotations"` and `test` are `GET` parameters. Usually you see numbers here, but people often put words as well. Each value has a key, in this case, `val` and `var`.

These parameters cannot contain special characters (such as spaces, question marks, or ampersands), but sometimes people need to put them there anyway. To solve this problem, coders `urlencode` all of their GET parameters. You can do this in PHP by using the `urlencode()` function.

```
echo 'http://example.com/test.php?val=' . urlencode('"quotations"') . '&var='. urlencode('test');
//  http://example.com/test.php?val=%22quotations%22&var=test
```

If you just need to do this once, you can encode things here:

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/